# How to push the result of an asynchronous REST call to the client using REST and Kafka

Tags: java, rest, apache-kafka, microservices

I want to deploy a scalable set of microservices. Every service should communicate via REST to each other. Also I need to request third-party services which will be slow and unstable. 
So I came up with the idea to make it event-driven and use apache kafka.

Something like:

WebClient_X--request--->LoadBalancer--forward-->A-Service_1--request--->ThirdPartyService

A_Service_1 needs to poll the ThirdPartyService for the results and writes them into kafka.

A_Service_1--->Kafka

Now what?

How is it possible to send the results stored in the kafka topic back to the requesting WebClient_X. 
Remember:
- A-Service is deployed N-times behind the LB.
- the A-Service_1 instance returned a Response.created(uuid) to the WebClient

On solution would be to make the WebClient consume the kafka topic. But this seems to be a stupid idea.

Answer (score 0):

After think about it a lot I came up with the following idea :

all instances of a_service consume the Kafka topic equaly (no balancing)

the results are stored in a  cache (local)

the webclient needs to poll for the result with the UUID.

In the Future I will replace the cache with a redis cluster or a clustered memcache.

An alternativ to polling would be websockets. But this seems to have some downsizes.